# posting on the facebook app page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm able to post to a users wall using android application. but i have another request to post to a specific app page (which is created for the same app). But i couldn't find any resource regarding this...

can anyone help how to archive this...

So far to share on users wall this piece of code is working..

```
private void postOnFB(byte[] data) {
    try {
        Log.v("postImage", "in");
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("description", "Play this awesome bible game..");
        params.putByteArray("picture", data);
        params.putString("message", facebookPostingMessage
                + "\n http://www.momaco.lk/");
        mAsyncFacebookRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST",
                new SampleUploadListener(), null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do nothing only to catch exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please can some one help me on this...

Answer (score 0):

You can post to the app page's wall by issuing an HTTP POST request to the app page's feed connection:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/APP_PAGE_ID/feed
```

That is, you code should read

```
   mAsyncFacebookRunner.request(APP_PAGE_ID + "/feed", params, "POST",
            new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

Note that its the app's page id you post to, not the app id.

Comment: where can i find this app_page_id??

Comment: Use page name to post request. For example, graph.facebook.com/pepsi returns the id ( together with other fields) for the pepsi page.

Comment: when i try to do what u said it gives me an error (OAuthException)
do you have any example code?

Comment: im getting this error  :(
 {"error":{"message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: Scripturize","type":"OAuthException","code":803}}

Comment: Something is wrong with your query. You need to ensure your page name in the query is the same as the one you registered on the developer pages. You can test your queries here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer